# Aligning buttons side by side

Tags: css, html

I am trying to align multiple buttons side by side and keep the responsive design.
Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Here is the jsfiddle link: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8zdhahnz/)

```css
.round-button {
  width: 25%;
}
.round-button-circle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid #cfdcec;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #4679BD;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
}
.round-button-circle:hover {
  background: #30588e;
}
.round-button a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #e2eaf3;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="round-button">
  <div class="round-button-circle">
    <a href="http://example.com" class="round-button">Button!!</a>
    <a href="http://example.com" class="round-button">Button!!</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what you mean side by side

Comment: you want two circles side by side

Comment: yes, i want them side by side

Comment: you can simplify the markup a lot and just use a single `<a>` for a button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want two buttons in two different circles, then [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8zdhahnz/5/) is the solution.

You should change your html structure to this:

```
<div class="round-button">
  <div class="round-button-circle">
    <a href="http://example.com" class="round-button">Button!!</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="round-button">
  <div class="round-button-circle">
    <a href="http://example.com" class="round-button">Button!!</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is the css code:

```
.round-button {
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
.round-button-circle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 10px solid #cfdcec;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #4679BD;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
}
.round-button-circle:hover {
    background: #30588e;
}
.round-button a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #e2eaf3;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 3vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Change your `font-size` to `3vw` for an even better responsiveness. Try to resize [it here](https://jsfiddle.net/8zdhahnz/3/)

Comment: @Jose Rui Santos I edited and added your idea to my answer. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. We are all here to share and learn from each other

Answer (score 1):

This is just for your information , if you want the two buttons side by side there is no need too much of `div` you can simply do with one div and anchor tags, i have modified your code like this way , please Run the below snippet ,

```css
.button_wrap {
 text-align:center;
}
.button_wrap a {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 10px solid #cfdcec;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #4679BD;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
 display:inline-table;
 text-align: center;
    color: #e2eaf3;
    font-family: Verdana;
 font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
 margin:0 5px;
}
.button_wrap a span {
 display:table-cell;
 vertical-align:middle;
}
.button_wrap a:hover {
    background: #30588e;
}
```

```html
<div class="button_wrap">
    <a href="http://example.com"><span>Buttons</span></a>
    <a href="http://example.com"><span>Buttons</span></a>
</div><!-- /.button_wrap -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to

```
.round-button {
    width: 50%;
}
.round-button-circle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 10px solid #cfdcec;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #4679BD;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
}
.round-button-circle:hover {
    background: #30588e;
}
.round-button a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #e2eaf3;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The problem was that the buttons had `100%` `width`. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8zdhahnz/1/).

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
.round-button {
    width: 25%;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```css
.round-button {
    width: 25%;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
}
.round-button-circle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 10px solid #cfdcec;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #4679BD;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
}
.round-button-circle:hover {
    background: #30588e;
}
.round-button a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #e2eaf3;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="round-button">
  <div class="round-button-circle">
    <a href="http://example.com" class="round-button">Button!!</a>
    <a href="http://example.com" class="round-button">Button!!</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="round-button">
  <div class="round-button-circle">
    <a href="http://example.com" class="round-button">Button!!</a>
    <a href="http://example.com" class="round-button">Button!!</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="round-button">
  <div class="round-button-circle">
    <a href="http://example.com" class="round-button">Button!!</a>
    <a href="http://example.com" class="round-button">Button!!</a>
  </div>
</div>
```